# Is $(x+1)/(x^2-1)$ defined for $x=-1$?

Tags: functions, arithmetic, fractions

It might sound like a silly question, but I can't come up with a clear answer.
By looking at the expression, the answer should be "no", since $(-1)^2=1$ and we're in trouble.

However, if I factorize: $(x^2-1) =(x+1)(x-1)$, $x=-1$ is still illegal. But now the terms cancel out and I am left with $1/(x-1)$, which is clearly defined for $x=-1$?

What happened? Was some information lost in the manipulation or was the original expression an "illusion"? I hope my question makes sense.

Comment: Notice how at $-1$, you have $0/0$, which is indeterminate, rather than undefined, which are different.

Comment: @dbanet I'd say that from one (indeterminate) follows the other one (undefined...because it is indeterminate). The other way around isn't necessarily true, of course.

Comment: "cancellation" is hidden division.  To cancel the $(x-1)$ term you need to divide both numerator and denominator by $(x-1)$ and since division by $0$ is bad, you need to assume that $x\ne 1$ in order to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There was some information lost - the division by $(x+1)$ is only valid when $x\ne-1$, since otherwise we are dividing by $0$. The function $\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$ will have a hole at $x=-1$ (value does not exist), but is otherwise identical to $\frac{1}{x-1}$.

Answer (score 5):

One way to look at it is to realize $\frac {ab}{ac} = \frac{b}{c}$ only if $a \ne 0$  If $a = 0$ then we can not say $\frac{ab}{ac} = \frac{b}{c}$.  Of course we can not say $\frac{ab}{ac}$ equals *anything*.

So we can not say $\frac{x+1}{x^2 - 1} = \frac 1{x - 1}$.  We *can* say  $\frac{x+1}{x^2 - 1} =\begin{cases} \frac 1{x - 1}; x\ne -1;\text{(Note:}\frac 1{x - 1}\text{ is undefined if } x =1\text{)} \\\text{undefined}; x= -1 \end{cases}  $

This is a subtly different statement altogether.

Answer (score 4):

This is what's called a removable singularity. In this case, we have that

$$\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$$

exists and is equal to $\lim_{x\to -1}\frac{1}{x-1}=-\frac12$, so setting the value of that function as $-\frac12$ yields a new function that is equal to the old one wherever the old one is defined $(\mathbb{R}\setminus\{-1\})$ and also continuous in the new point of definition $(x=-1)$.

Comment: Cheers man! Thanks for the answer.

Comment: @Henry1981 **Still** ...the *original* function's undefined at $\;x=-1\;$

Answer (score 3):

It is the exact same problem as saying:

*Is $x/x$ defined for $x=0$ ?*

The answer is **no**.

Even if you could change the formula with algebra to give it a value (which would obviously make sense), it is not defined *per se*.

Answer (score 3):

The expression $\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}$ is undefined at $x=-1$ for the reason that you give: the denominator is $0$. And of course $\frac1{x-1}=-\frac12$ when $x=-1$. The explanation is that the two expressions are equal **only where both are defined**. It’s not true without qualification that

$$\frac{x+1}{x^2-1}=\frac1{x-1}\;;$$

the equality is valid only for those values of $x$ for which both expressions are defined. That excludes both $x=1$, where neither is defined, and $x=-1$, where the first is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is not defined for the reasons you've stated above. To factorize, you divided by $(x+1)$, which is equal to zero, so it is an error.